# SELECT DISTINCT incorrect name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

| ID | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Char |
| 2 | Bob Maff |
| 3 | 458 |
| 4 | hi789 |
| 5 | Kate Mill |
| 6 | 33332263333226 |

and I want select only incorrect name, like this:

| ID | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 458 |
| 4 | hi789 |
| 6 | 33332263333226 |

I think about it that way and how correct is that?

```
select * from table 
where full_name like '%1%' 
   or full_name like '%2%' 
   or full_name like '%3%' 
   or full_name like '%4%' 
   or full_name like '%5%' 
   or full_name like '%6%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows that "invalid names" are those that contain digits. If that's so, for sample data

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID FULL_NAME
---------- --------------
         1 Joe Char
         2 Bob Maff
         3 458
         4 hi789
         5 Kate Mill
         6 33332263333226

6 rows selected.
```

query you might be using is

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  where regexp_instr(full_name, '\d') > 0;

        ID FULL_NAME
---------- --------------
         3 458
         4 hi789
         6 33332263333226

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your correct names have a space character in them so the incorrect ones do not have a space:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  full_name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Or, it could be when they have a digit character:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(full_name, '\d');
```

Or, without (slow) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  TRANSLATE(full_name, '0123456789', '----------' ) != full_name;
```